# Editing the weight of many product variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

How can I edit the weight of many product variations in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1):

First you get an array of your Product Variations IDs this way:

```
global $wpdb;
$posts_table = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$variation_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT `ID` FROM $posts_table WHERE `post_status` LIKE 'publish' AND `post_type` LIKE 'product_variation'");
```

Then you can edit the weight for this product variations this way:

```
// Iterating through all product variations
foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){

    // Get an instance of the product variation object
    $variation_object = wc_get_product($variation_id);

    // Get the variation weight
    $weight = $variation_object->get_weight();


    ## -- USE CONDITIONS TO SET / UPDATE WEIGHT AS YOU NEED -- ##

    // Example of conditions below
    if( $weight <= 0.2 && $weight > 0.3 ){
        $variation_object->set_weight(0.28);
    } elseif( $weight <= 0.3 && $weight > 0.5 ){
        $variation_object->set_weight(0.42);
    }

    // Example of empty weight condition
    if( empty($weight) ){
        $variation_object->set_weight(0.16);
    }

    // Example Based on variation IDs from 125 to 129
    if($variation_id >= 125 &&  $variation_id < 130 ){
        $variation_object->set_weight(0.45);
    }
}
```

> **Then you can customize the conditions to match your needs and to embed this in a function to run it once.**
>
> You can use any [**`WC_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_weight) and [**`WC_Product_Variation`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html#_get_weight) methods on the Product Variation object **`$variation_object`** in your conditions too.
>
> **This way you will set / update all your multiple needed variations weight**

Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php file.

**This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 3.0+**